# GET http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/141798 500 (Internal Server Error) In React+Node+SQL Server application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my React+Node+SQL Server application I get this error

> GET http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/141798 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have setup my endpoint urls in the server as follows:

`dboperations.js`

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');
const { response } = require('express');

async function getallcustomerOrders(){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .query("SELECT * FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] order by ID desc");
        return orders.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function getcustomerOrders(orderNumber) {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.NChar, orderNumber)
            .query("SELECT ID,cmt FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] where LTRIM(ord_no) = LTRIM(@input_parameter)");
        return orders.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function updateComments(ID) {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .input('ID', sql.NChar, ID)
            .query(`SELECT cmt FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] WHERE ID = @ID`);

        let order = orders.recordset.length ? orders.recordset[0] : null;
        if (order) {
            await pool.request()
                .input('cmt', req.body.cmt)
                .query(`UPDATE [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] SET cmt = @cmt WHERE ID = @ID;`);

            order = { ...order, ...req.body };

            response.json(order);
        } else {
            response.status(404).json({
                message: 'Record not found'
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).json(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getallcustomerOrders : getallcustomerOrders,
    getcustomerOrders : getcustomerOrders,
    updateComments : updateComments
}
```

`api.js`

```
var Db = require('./dboperations');
var dboperations = require('./dboperations');

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
const { request, response } = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', router);

router.use((request,response,next)=> {
    console.log('middleware');
    next();
})

router.route('/customerOrder').get((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.getallcustomerOrders().then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0]);
    })
})

router.route('/customerOrder/:orderNumber').get((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.getcustomerOrders(request.params.orderNumber).then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0]);
    })
})

router.route('/customerOrder/:ID').put((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.updateComments(request.params.ID).then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0]);
    })
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Customer Order API is running at ' + port);

dboperations.getcustomerOrders().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})

dboperations.getallcustomerOrders().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})

dboperations.updateComments().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

and calling it in the `EmailFaxDetails.js` file. Once I type in the order number I get the above error. The order number does exist in the database and once I try the `GET` method via `POSTMAN` it gives me back the correct response.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import FetchOrderDetails from './FetchOrderDetails';
import axios from 'axios'
import '../App.css';

const EmailFaxDetails = () => {

    const [orderNumber, setOrderNumber] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState([]);
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/${orderNumber}`
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          setId(response.data)
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }, [url]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setOrderNumber(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsShown(true);
    console.log(orderNumber);
  }

    return(
        <div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            Order Number: <input placeholder="Order Number" type="text" id="message" name="message" onChange={handleChange} value={orderNumber} autoComplete="off" />
                {id.map((idnum) => (
                    <div key={idnum.ID}>
                    {isShown && <FetchOrderDetails ord_no={orderNumber} cmt={idnum.cmt} id={idnum.ID}/>}
                    </div>
                ))} 
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EmailFaxDetails;
```

[image: Error Console Log]

[image: Node Output]

What might be the issue here and how should I fix this?

Comment: Your api `console.logs` errors (in dboperations.js), what is that error message?

Comment: I just added the pic of error logs above. Once I enter the order number I get those error msg's

Comment: Your api is not bubbling error messages up back to the client so this isn't showing the console.log output from the api.  You need to get the output from wherever the api is actually running.

Comment: Sorry I thought the regular console logs, okay I added a pic of the node console. There are no errors showing in that except showing me the correct result.

Comment: Ok, getting there.  The node output you added is just the last bit of what was written to the console from the last call to your api.  We need to see the _exact_ error message from the call to `getcustomerOrders()`.  You'll probably need to scroll up in the terminal to see it.  If you're having a hard time spotting it, comment out all the other console.logs in api.js and dboperations.js so that only the `getcustomerOrders` function writes output.

Comment: Understood, does the new picture helps? That was the only error that I could find...

Comment: Well, that is an error resulting from a call to `updateComments()`.  But that made me notce the 3 calls at the bottom of api.js.  What are those there for, testing?  You're not passing parameter values to `getcustomerOrders` or `updateComments` in those calls which would throw exceptions.

Comment: I was able to make a little improvement, I did edit the code at `dboperations.js` updateComments(ID). Specifically I edit the `response` to `res` and while that error has gone another one. `(node:41380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');
const { res } = require('express');

async function getallcustomerOrders(){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .query("SELECT * FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] order by ID desc");
        return orders.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function getcustomerOrders(orderNumber){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.NChar, orderNumber)
            .query("SELECT ID,cmt FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] where LTRIM(ord_no) = LTRIM(@input_parameter)");
        return orders.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function updateComments(orderNumber){
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.NChar, orderNumber)
            .query(`SELECT cmt FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] WHERE ord_no = @input_parameter`);

        let order = orders.recordset.length ? orders.recordset[0] : null;
        if (order) {
            await pool.request()
                .input('cmt', req.body.cmt)
                .query(`UPDATE [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] SET cmt = @cmt WHERE ord_no = @input_parameter;`);

            order = { ...order, ...req.body };

            res.json(order);
        } else {
             res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Record not found'
            }); 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        //res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getallcustomerOrders : getallcustomerOrders,
    getcustomerOrders : getcustomerOrders,
    updateComments : updateComments
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).